# I want to insert a record based on the condition. If column value contains bracket then it should insert one record otherwise insert depending upon

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE new_staging(
    e_id     NUMBER(10),
    e_owner  VARCHAR2(255)
        CONSTRAINT pk_new_staging PRIMARY KEY
( E_ID ) );

insert into new_staging values(1,'AUZA, PAUL OSA');
insert into new_staging values(2,'PAUL, REXX OSA');
insert into new_staging values(3,'PAUL, REXX OSA (PR56789)');
insert into new_staging values(4,'PAUL, REXX, OSA');

CREATE SEQUENCE new_target_sq;

CREATE TABLE new_target(
    t_id     NUMBER(10) DEFAULT new_target_sq.NEXTVAL NOT NULL,
    e_id     NUMBER(10),
    t_owner  VARCHAR2(30),
    sort_order number(30),
        CONSTRAINT pk_new_target PRIMARY KEY
( T_ID ) , CONSTRAINT FK_NEW_TARGET_E_ID FOREIGN KEY ( E_ID ) REFERENCES NEW_STAGING ( E_ID ));
```

I want to insert the values into the new_target table based on the conditions as below in the select query. Currently, I am validating whether e_owner contains a comma or not. If it contains then it is selecting that many rows. Suppose, e_id contains AUZA, PAUL OSA then it should insert two records into the new_target table and likewise for three commas. But if the column has bracket () in the e_owner column then it should insert only one record for e.g for e_id 3

Below is the select query which is doing the work of comma-separated only but need to include logic to handle '(' as well.

```
select e_id
        ,trim(regexp_substr(e_owner, '[^,]+', 1, level)) as owner,
        level as sort_order
  from   new_staging
  connect by e_id = prior e_id
         and level <= regexp_count(e_owner, ',') + 1
         and prior sys_guid() is not null
```

Also, while inserting the record it is throwing an error.

```
insert into new_target(t_id,e_id,t_owner,sort_order) 
(t_id.nextval,select e_id
        ,trim(regexp_substr(e_owner, '[^,]+', 1, level)) as owner
        ,level as sort_order
  from   new_staging
  connect by e_id = prior e_id
         and level <= regexp_count(e_owner, ',') + 1
         and prior sys_guid() is not null);
```

Once, I build the logic for handling brackets then the whole thing I want to insert into the new_target table.

Comment: and the error is....?

Comment: @OldProgrammer It is because select is missing but it's there and t_id should be populated by nextval. ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword this is the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into new_target(t_id, e_id, t_owner, sort_order)
select NEW_TARGET_SQ.nextval,e_id
         ,case when e_owner like '%(%' then e_owner else trim(regexp_substr(e_owner, '[^,]+', 1, level)) end,
         level
   from   new_staging
   connect by e_id = prior e_id
          and level <= regexp_count(case when e_owner like '%(%' then 'x' else e_owner end, ',') + 1
          and prior sys_guid() is not null
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).